# How to remove Python in Cent OS?

Tags: python, linux, centos

How to remove python 2.6 from Cent OS?
I tried command `yum remove python`. After `python --version` and get again

Comment: This question hints of serious problems behind the intent. Usually, we don't manually remove or upgrade core dependency packages of a distribution. Python is one of the dependencies. If you your intent is to remove, in order to get a python version you want, then I will suggest you use `virtualenv` to get the specific desired version just for the script or application you need to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is required by many of the Linux distributions. Many system utilities the distro providers combine (both GUI based and not), are programmed in Python.

The version of python the system utilities are programmed in I will call the "main" python. For Ubuntu 12.04 e.g. this is 2.7.3, the version that you get when invoking python on a freshly installed system.

Because of the system utilities that are written in python it is impossible to remove the main python without breaking the system. It even takes a lot of care to update the main python with a later version in the same major.minor series, as you need to take care of compiling it with the same configuration specs as the main python. This is needed to get the correct search paths for the libraries that the main python uses, which is often not exactly what a .configure without options would get you, when you download python to do a python compilation from source.

Installing a different version from the major.minor version the system uses (i.e. the main python) normally is not a problem. I.e. you can compile a 2.6 or 3.4 python and install it without a problem, as this is installed next to the main (2.7.X) python. Sometimes a distro provides these different major.minor packages, but they might not be the latest bug-release version in that series.

The problems start when you want to use the latest in the main python series (e.g. 2.7.8 on a system with main python version is 2.7.3). I recommend not trying to replace the main python, but instead to compile and install the 2.7.8 in a separate location (mine is in /opt/python/2.7.8). This will keep you on the security fix schedule of your distribution and guarantees someone else tests compatibility of the python libraries and against that version (as used by system utilities!).

Comment: @Goga Please to this page  **http://www.techtransit.org/install-python-3-on-centos-rhel-fedora-cloudlinux/**